# GLPK/Linear Programming - if conditions

Tags: linear-programming

Imagine that I have two variables **fw** (>= 0) and **a** (binary) and my objective function is to `minimize: fw`.

In the constraints part, I want to ensure (among other things that are not important here) that **if fw > 0, then a == 1**. To ensure this, I used the following expression:

```
M * a >= fw; #(M is a big constant)
```

The problem is I also want to ensure that when **fw == 0, then a == 0** , and the restriction above is not sufficient (due to the fact that **a** is not in the objective function). Is there any way to ensure this without adding **a** to the objective function?

Comment: Se also [express-boolean-logic-operations-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/express-boolean-logic-operations-in-zero-one-integer-linear-programming-ilp) on cs.stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume `M=upper bound of fw` (choose as small as possible). Then

```
0.01 a <= fw <= M a
```